# Show all navigation levels in navigation panel

Tags: navigation, term-store, breadcrumb, categories

I am creating a Wiki for our organization and I have split up the different topics into categories. These are built using a Term Set. The issue I am having is navigating to any page in a category hides all the other links except the ones in that category.
[image]

The links are created custom using the Term Store Management Tool

[image]

How can I change the navigation (or site structure) to show all of the pages no matter what? I don't want users to have to click on the logo to navigate to the home page just to see the whole navigation panel.

If there is a better way of organizing an Enterprise Wiki, what would that look like?

Comment: Are all the linked pages on same SharePoint site or the links are navigating to other sites/subsites?